# How to reference a function from one .m file in another?

Tags: objective-c, class, file, nsmutablearray, compiler-errors

this is a bit of a newbie question but I can't seem to find it anywhere. I have defined a class in a set of .h/.m files and have a separate .h/.m for drawing. What I'm trying to do is create an array of objects from this class, and draw them sequentially to the screen.

Of course, I'm getting a `'squares' undeclared (first use in this function)` error. I went around in circles for a while, with lots of duplicate code, before I admitted that I don't know how to do this and went to seek help here.

In one .h file:
`@interface DrawerViewController : UIViewController {

 NSMutableArray *squares;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *squares;

@end`

In the corresponding .m:
`squares = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`

In another .m file, where I want to access the "squares" array:

`if ([squares objectAtIndex:thisID] != NULL) {`

And that's where I'm getting the error: `"squares" undeclared.` I'm using `include` to bring in the other .h file, but that doesn't seem to be working.

If someone can point me in the right direction, I will be very grateful...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'squares' attribute is a member of another object, therefore you can't directly send messages to it.  In the second .m file, create an object of type DrawerViewController and call 'if ([[myDrawerViewController squares] objectAtIbdex: thisId])'.  If you've #included the other file that should compile fine.  In essence, you're nesting two message calls there... The first retrieves the squares property and the second sends a message to that proprty asking for the array member.

Comment: Hmm, I'm getting `'DrawerViewController' may not respond to '+squares'`. Have I missed a step? Sorry...

Comment: Yes, you do not ask for `[DrawerViewController squares]` because that would give you the error you're seeing, you need to instantiate an object of type `DrawerViewController`, called (for example) `myDrawerViewController`, and then do as @samkass said. In this sense Objective C is no different from Java or C++ - you need to invoke a method on an object.

Comment: (You'll also need a `@synthesize squares;` in your implementation of `DrawerViewController`. That _is_ unique to ObjC.)

Comment: Ah! Thanks samkass and Echelon, I get it now!

Comment: If I can return to this and rephrase in newbie language: You can't send a message over to another 'physical' file, i.e. `DrawerViewController`. Instead, you need to make a pointer to one from within in your current class and send messages to this. (I'm sure this is mega-obvious to anyone with a CS background, but I'm coming to Obj-C from Processing, where all of this is taken care of and the camp counselors tuck us in at night.)